# cant find mongo in database addition redhat openshift

Tags: mongodb, openshift, redhat

I'm a newbie trying to set up a mongo image on openshift sandbox, I saw others do it on YouTube with no problem, but for some reason I cant seem to find the mongo image

[image]

I pressed on "Add+" in the side menu, then selected "Database" under "Developer Catalog"
[image]
There is no mongo option,
The closest I got to finding a mongo image is selecting the "Other" option and searching for mongo:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that because of Mongo's change in the MongoDB license that it can no longer be included in official Red Hat containers/images.

You, of course, can still use community built MongoDB images. But Red Hat can't distribute anymore. Here is a related KB article, although it's targeted for RHEL, not OpenShift: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6188061